# Command Line Input in C

Tags: c

I made a program that inputs thru the command line 2 variables.

If the input was 5 15 the output should be:

```
0.00 15.00 30.00 45.00 60.00
1.00 0.97 0.87 0.71 0.50
```

However in the command prompt whenever I type 5 15 I get:

```
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

char buff[256];
double length;
double stepSize;
double cosValue;
double val = PI / 180.0;
double i;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    length = atof(argv[1]);
    stepSize = atof(argv[2]);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        double stepSizeEdit = stepSize * i;
        printf("%.2lf ", stepSizeEdit);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        double stepSizeEdit = stepSize * i;
        cosValue = cos(stepSizeEdit * val);
        printf("%.2lf ", cosValue);
    }
}
```

The part that takes in the command line argument is this:

```
length = atof(argv[1]);
stepSize = atof(argv[2]);
```

Here I am converting the argv values from strings to doubles, is this incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? e.g. print the `length` and `stepsize` to see if they contain the expected values.

Comment: Have you made any effort to figure this out yourself, such as `printf` output of the `argv[1]` and `arg[2]` values and the contents of `length` and `stepsize` after assigning to them? How about stepping through the code in the debugger? What does that tell you?

Comment: Length = 0

stepSize = 0

Comment: argc should be of type int not char.  It's always a good practice to use the gcc flag -Wall to catch all warnings.

Comment: Click that checkmark thingy to accept the answer. Then, everyone will know that this problem was solved and @LBes will get a nice reward for helping you out. :)

Comment: Thanks for being a good member of the community. :)

Comment: Note that the global variables should all be made into local variables.  There's no need for any globals in this code, and in general it is a good idea to avoid using global variables whenever possible.  It isn't always possible, but it often is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When trying to compile your code, I get the following warning:

```
test.c:15:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atof' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        length = atof(argv[1]);
```

This `implicit declaration` points you towards the problem. You did not include `stdlib.h`
Include it and your program will work.

Without the include the function `atof()` is declared implicitly. 
When GCC doesn't find a declaration (which is the case if you don't include the header needed), it assumes this implicit declaration: int `atof()`;, which means the function can receive whatever you give it, and returns an integer.

This is considered an error (implicit declarations) in newer C standards (C99, C11). However, gcc doesn't implement these standards by default, so you still get the warning with older standards (that you're using I suppose).

To better find these kind of errors I suggest your turn on and read the compiler warnings. You should also give this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) a read to learn about them.

As pointed by @JonathanLeffler, you should also avoid the use of global variables :).